# System.IO.FileNotFoundException "Could not find file" even after manually typing file Path

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, file-io, filenotfoundexception

I tried to use the method
`System.IO.File.Move(sourceFile,newFilePath);`
to rename a File, but I always get the same error message, that my file couldn't be found.

I tried to manually write the source Path

`System.IO.File.Move(@"D:\Users\XXX\Desktop\TestOrHMoin",@"D:\Users\XXX\Desktop\TestOrHMoinNEW");`
but I still get the same ERROR Message.

This is my full code

`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openfiledialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (openfiledialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                oldFilePath = openfiledialog.FileName;
                listBox1.Items.Add(oldFilePath);
                            
            }
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            newFilePath = textBox1.Text;
            oldFilePath = oldFilePath.Remove(oldFilePath.Length-newFilePath.Length);
            newFilePath = oldFilePath + newFilePath;
            string sourceFile = @oldFilePath;
            string newFile = @newFilePath;
            MessageBox.Show(sourceFile);
            System.IO.File.Move(sourceFile,newFilePath);

            // This part is the real code, the above Part is for debugging/testing
            //System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(sourceFile);       
            //if (fi.Exists)
            //{
            //    fi.MoveTo(newFilePath);
            //    MessageBox.Show("Erfolgreich geändert");
            //} else { MessageBox.Show("Abbruch"); }
        }
```

`

Comment: What type of file is `TestOrHMoin`? Does it have an extension (e.g `TestOrHMoin.txt`?) Bearing in mind that the extension might be hidden in Windows Explorer.

Comment: Its a Folder, so there shouldn't be any additions I missed.

Comment: Ah. To move a folder you should use [`Directory.Move`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.move?view=net-6.0) instead of File.Move.

Comment: @JohnWu thank you for recommending it to me, but for now, I am happy that my code runs at all...

Answer (score 0):

oldFilePath = oldFilePath.Remove(oldFilePath.Length-newFilePath.Length);
was wrong

I needed to declare another variable, so oldFilePath gets untouched. It was my error. I still don't know, why the manuell direction got an error.